# Ksoap on android-- get a list response from a java web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, list, android-ksoap2

I have a java web service (soap) which i want to use with an android client for that am using ksoap.

My web service gives an answer which look like this :

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:listealbumResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws/">
            <return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:album">
                <annee>2008</annee>
                <id>6</id>
                <titre>Ninja Tuna</titre>
            </return>
            <return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:album">
                <annee>2008</annee>
                <id>10</id>
                <titre>Fine Music, Vol. 1</titre>
            </return>
            <return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:album">
                <annee>2004</annee>
                <id>14</id>
                <titre>Bob Acri</titre>
            </return>
            <return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:album">
                <annee>2009</annee>
                <id>54</id>
                <titre>Rated R</titre>
            </return>
        </ns2:listealbumResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

***wich is a list of object***

To call my web service  i use this code :

```
try{
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = false;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

When i tested my response "result" it's got only one object , how could i get all the list and parse it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that when i parse the  soap response i got only the first object of the list so i changer this line :

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

with :

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

wiht that i got all the list and i add this

```
testValues = new String[result.getPropertyCount()];
    for(int i= 0; i< result.getPropertyCount(); i++){
        testValues[i] = result.getProperty(i).toString(); 

    }
```

Good luck and thank you Janusz

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;    
String output = "";    
for(int i= 0; i< result.getPropertyCount(); i++){
    SoapObject object = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(i);

    output += "annee : " + object.getProperty("annee") + "\n";
    output += "id : " + object.getProperty("id") + "\n";
    output += "titre : " + object.getProperty("titre") + "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is a single [SoapObject](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject.html) this objects however should have a property for every item in the list that you requested. You could do something like this to retrieve all the items:

```
private static List parseLists(List listItems, SoapObject response) {
    int propertyCount = response.getPropertyCount();
    for (int currentProperty = 0; currentProperty < propertyCount; currentProperty++) {
        Object input = response.getProperty(currentProperty);
        Object result = parseObject(input.toString());
        if (result != null) {
            listItems.add(result);
        }
    }
    return listItems;
}
```

Comment: Hi,  
thank you for answering i'll try to give more details :

Am expecting something like this from my web service 
{{"id1";"year";"title"};{"id2";"year";"title"}}

but in my soapObject i got : 
{"id1";"year";"titl"}

i would like to retrieve the list of the objects